# Spring Boot - Graphql - Access Headers from arbitrary resolver code

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, http-headers, graphql

I'm using GraphQL (Spring Boot, Kotlin), and I have a specific issue with headers.

We need the client to send three pieces of information that we combine to retrieve internal sensitive data. That data is then used inside resolver codes.

Getting the headers from rest is as easy as `@RequestHeader`, but in GraphQL it has proved quite challenging. Is there a way I can save the headers to check for the three pieces of information I need?

I looked closely at spring security, but I can't figure out how to get a custom method to work in my method chain, much less save the headers in a way that I can access them from the domain layer.

I could always simply request the auth as a GraphQL type, but that puts a fairly high burden on the client and complicates the schema.

Any and all feedback is welcome.

Comment: if i understand you want to save request headers into graphql so you can do something like this firstly you need to create genericfilterbean and then get request object from there and take what you want and import to graphql after all  call chain.dofilter(..) -> this make system go on ordered other filters you can search data after all process is done . check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL has a FetchDataEnvironment. You can use it by passing FetchDataEnvironment as the last variable in any resolver/query. Then, just call 
`environment.getContext<GraphQLEnvironentClass>().getHttpServletRequest.headers()`

To anyone in the future - I'm sorry this code isn't exact, but your strong typing in your IDE will show you what I mean.